# Live555media server error on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: 21.10

I have tried to install livemedia-utils via the Ubuntu 21.10 terminal but it is not working. Can anyone please help?

Comment: That isn't enough information. Please [edit] your question to include the output of running `sudo apt update && sudo apt install livemedia-utils` in a terminal.

Comment: `livemedia-utils` was last distributed with Ubuntu 20.10 and also available in 18.04 and 20.04. That's all.